# Security reporting tool

Tags: linux, security

Does something like security intrusion reporting tool exist in Linux? Something that would report (after logging in) security/system change things like that:

```
Failed Login Attempts: 
jsmith from 1.2.3.4 against example-host performed 37 times 
Account changes: 
New user: name=c0rt3z uid=1050 
...
```

P.S.: sorry if this is duplicate, i don't know how is this type of things in Linux named

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question because it's so general. There exist many security features in Linux, some of which are provided by the base operating system and others by standalone applications. The specifics of these vary between distributions so without knowing what Linux distribution you are using it is hard to make concrete suggestions.

I highly recommend you start with your distribution's security guide or general documentation.

A few ideas to get you started:

- the **syslog** facility, specifically `auth.log`: authenication information is logged here
- **logwatch**: a tool to help you sort and parse logfiles for the information you care about
- **Fail2Ban**: automatically drops IP addresses of clients who pass a threshold for number of login failures
- **Tripwire**: monitors files for changes
- **AppArmor**, or **SELinux**: Mandatory Access Control mechanisms for applications and the kernel.
- **Auditd**: userspace auditing for file modification (similar to tripwire)
- Shell history logging (e.g., `~/.bash_history`).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I can think of, which avoids getting to grips with serious auditing tools, is to just install **logwatch**.

You can then receive daily emails listing (among many useful bits of information) a summary of failed login attempts, along with newly created users and groups.

Comment: this seems to be too simple, but thanks, maybe I'll try it

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is [Samhain](http://www.la-samhna.de/samhain/). It will monitor your system for changes and notify you, but it's a bit more proactive than just whenever you happen to log in.

I used to use Osiris for this kind of thing, but it hasn't been updated in years.

By the way, this kind of security auditing is called **Host Integrity Monitoring**.

Comment: Samhain is a new one to me. I generally don't have much interest in Host Integrity Monitoring systems, but it seems pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways you could protect your server against a 'brute-force' attack. Some of these methods are more difficult to implement but in the long term can give you better security.

If you want a real simple solution you could implement [Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). For something more advanced you can implement the same basic functionality by using [iptables hashlimits](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables).

You could also disable password based authentication in sshd, move it to a non-standard port, or setup a proper firewall.

Because this question really falls down a rabbit hole that has created an entire industry I'd suggest you look at a security guide for your linux distribution. The [Ubuntu guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Security) is a good start.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I've already disabled password auth, moved ssh to non-standard port and I use denyhosts against ssh bruteforce. I'm not looking for these systems to secure Linux box, I'm looking for something that will warn me for system changes caused probably by attackers.

Answer (score 0):

No one mentioned [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/).

Some examples:

FTP server:

```
Received From: (x) 192.168.4.x->/var/log/secure
Rule: 11210 fired (level 10) -> "Multiple failed login attempts."
Portion of the log(s):

Jul 23 22:52:50 x proftpd[5243]: x.localdomain (::ffff:x.x.x.x[::ffff:x.x.x.x]) - Maximum login attempts (3) exceeded, connection refused
```

SSH server:

```
Sep 17 12:38:00 x sshd[6995]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=x user=y
```

and web server:

```
Received From: x->/var/log/httpd/error_log
Rule: 30109 fired (level 9) -> "Attempt to login using a non-existent user."
Portion of the log(s):

[Fri Dec 03 23:27:59 2010] [error] [client x] user mBGq7XfBP7ZPs not found: /
```